# How to set push notification?

Tags: php, ios, ssl, push-notification

I have set push notification in my application. In my old server, notification work correctly. But, if I change the server, then the notification does not come and gives the error:

> APNS Connection Failed: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

Please tell me how to solve this error SSL certificate also in server.

Comment: Can you check your port at 10060? Is it open?